# How to verify a dropdown which is an extended web element is disabled in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a dropdown which is disabled and I have to verify the same. How can I do it  with an assert statement or any other method?

Comment: Which language binding ? Java ? C# ? J's

Comment: What is the purpose of validating the values of a disabled dropdown, given that your users can't use it?

Answer (score 1):

In case *isEnabled* is not working:

1. Verify the DOM which may be having some attributes to represent it is disabled
2. And then use *element.getAttribute("attName");*

If it doesn't work, you can go with the exception. Try to select a value as mentioned in the above code, surround it with try block and capture the result in your catch block.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the dropdown WebElement this way;

```
WebElement testDropDown = driver.findElement(By.id("testingDropdown"));  
Select dropdown = new Select(testDropDown);
```

But to check whether it is disabled, you can use isEnabled();

```
boolean isEnabledDropDown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("dropdown_xpath")).isEnabled();
```

Check the isEnabled() [documentation](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api/2.50.1/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isEnabled--)

Therefore to assert that;

```
Assert.assertTrue(isEnabledDropDown);
```